# Play for Scala: Logger prints "?" instead of class name

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, logback

I have the following configuration in `logback.xml`:

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <encoder>
    <pattern>%coloredLevel %logger{15} - %class{36} - %message%n%xException{10}</pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>
```

And log with the following statement

```
Logger.info("This is a message")
```

However the log prints `?` instead of the class name:

```
[info] application - ? - This is a message
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What does it print if you replace `%class{36}` with `%class{0}` ?

Comment: You can also use `%C` or `%class` if you do not want to reduce the number of characters of your class name.

Comment: I tried %C, %class and %class{0} and have same problem

Comment: Fetching the caller class can be slow according to the documentation, at the time this line is printed, the class name is not resolved yet.

Answer (score 1):

Because when using the `Logger` api like this, you get a default logger, which does not know the class.

You need to use `Logger` like this:

```
val log = Logger(this.getClass)
log.info("This is a message")
```

See for more information the [Play documentation on logging](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaLogging#The-Logging-API).

Comment: I tried your code exactly but nothing gets logged, what could be the issue? I also tried `Logger.info ("this is logged")` right after and that works fine (with the caveat that the class name is shown as `?`)

Comment: You have to edit the logback.xml file to make the logger for your class log at info level. 
`<logger name="your.package" level="INFO" />`
I really suggest you read the documentation.